# Flink StatsD Integration not pushing data to StatsD

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, statsd

We are using Flink `1.15.3` We added the below configuration to the flink-conf.yaml file

```
metrics.reporters: stsd
metrics.reporter.stsd.factory.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.statsd.StatsDReporterFactory
metrics.reporter.stsd.host: localhost
metrics.reporter.stsd.port: 8125
metrics.reporter.stsd.interval: 60 SECONDS


metrics.scope.jm: <host>.jobmanager
metrics.scope.jm.job: <host>.jobmanager.<job_name>
metrics.scope.operator: <host>.taskmanager.<job_name>.<operator_name>.<subtask_index>
metrics.scope.task: <host>.taskmanager.<job_name>.<task_name>.<subtask_index>
metrics.scope.tm: <host>.taskmanager
metrics.scope.tm.job: <host>.taskmanager.<job_name>
```

When we listen to the statsD port, we don't get any of the metrics. Is there anything that we are missing out? Is there a way to check if some parameter is not getting passed?

We just want default Flink metrics we dont want custom matrics